# How to add an image in the header in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming

Link: http://new.shiva-rahbaran.org/wordpress/

I would like to have a profile pic in the upper left part. I'm using the twentytwelve Wordpress theme.

The Result should be something like this:
http://shiva-rahbaran.org/

So, it can also be above the right side menu. Where and how to integrate in the Wordpress back-end with, my theme?

Best,
Amir

Comment: I really don't understand why you close this as unclear and downvote it AFTER @aibrean beautifully answered the question and solved what I was asking for (and AFTER I even marked the answer as correct and thanked her!).

I showed my state (1st link) and my objective (2nd link). Well I got my perfect answer anyway.

Comment: I thought it was clear. Perhaps not worded eloquently, but it was a simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend adding it as a widget since you probably aren't using a child theme (any updates to the theme would override your edits unless you put those in a child theme).

Upload the image. Get the path of the image after it uploads (click `Edit` in `Media Library` and the path is on the right side in a greyed well).

In the `Appearance > Widgets` area in the admin section, add a text widget above the sidebar widget that is creating the `Of Interest` section and then include the code

`<img src="path/to/image.jpg">`

To hide on small screens you will need to add a media query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .hide-mobile {
   display:none;
   }
}
```

You can change the width px to whatever your preference is. Devices vary.

Then you would append the class to the URL like `<img src="path/to/image.jpg" class="hide-mobile">`

Comment: omg, that was sooo easy. would've never expected that. 

just a short follow-up question: 
any idea how to hide the image for small screens (smartphones)?

btw, i'm using a child-theme.

Comment: You would need to have a media query. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

for Header you should edit the header.php file (of your theme), you can change the HTML code as you want.
for right side, like the other site, you can edit the sidebar.php file (of your theme), again you can change the HTML code as you want.

Enjoy your code.